# Strings to Integers

Tags: ruby, string, integer, alphabet

Say you have the string `"Hi"`. How do you get a value of `8`, `9` (`"H"` is the 8th letter of the alphabet, and `"i"` is the 9th letter). Then say, add `1` to those integers and make it `9`, `10` which can then be made back into the string `"Ij"`? Is it possible?

Comment: Wondering how you want to handle edge cases?  If you had "Yz" what would you expect the new string to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `ord` to get the ASCII index, and `chr` to bring it back.

```
'Hi'.chars.map{|x| (x.ord+1).chr}.join
```

Answer (score 3):

**Note** Cary Swoveland had already given a same answer in a comment to the question.

It is impossible to do that through the numbers 8 and 9 because these numbers do not contain information about the case of the letters. But if you do not insist on converting the string via the number 8 and 9, but instead more meaningful numbers like ASCII code, then you can do it like this:

```
"Hi".chars.map(&:next).join
# => "Ij"
```

Comment: I posted a solution below that does what OP wants. Adjust argument to rotate if you want to do a bigger shift. Granted I don't use the 8 and 9 like mentioned in the question, but the answer is very much in the spirit of the question I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an enumerable of character ordinals from a string using the `codepoints` method.

```
string = "Hi"

string.codepoints.map{|i| (i + 1).chr}.join
=> "Ij"
```

Answer (score 0):

Preserving case and assuming you want to wrap around at "Z":

```
upper = [*?A..?Z]
lower = [*?a..?z]
LOOKUP = (upper.zip(upper.rotate) + lower.zip(lower.rotate)).to_h
s.each_char.map { |c| LOOKUP[c] }.join
#=> "Ij"
```