# One Time Pad Cipher

Tags: ruby, encryption

In Ruby, I am building a "One Time Pad" Cipher for a project. Although, I already ran into something that I am not familiar with how to do. I need to change a character to an integer and then add an random number.

For the random number, I'll just use rand and then add that to the character. But how do I make the character into an integer that matches the value of that character (A = 1, B = 2, C = 3, etc.). Then how do I add the value of the random number to the character (which has been changed into an integer), and then change the sum of those two back into a character?

Thanks.

Comment: What happened to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24337461/strings-to-integers?

Comment: @sawa What happened with vote to close - dupe?

Comment: Not really, this is to solve a different problem. In this I need to add a random number, this is a "one time pad" cipher whereas the other was more of a Caesar Cipher.

Comment: If you have finished with the first question, the following would help people trying to help you: 1) Select a correct answer on first question. 2) Use the knowledge you gained from first question to build on it in the second. Repeating "how do I make the character into an integer" is why this question looks like a duplicate. Some code showing your attempt here would be useful too, so it is clearer where you are stuck, and what the difference between the questions is. If you are not ready to write the second piece of code yet, then  slow down a little and learn what you can from the first.

Comment: Alright, Thanks dude. I will use your instructions as stated above the next time I ask a question on the website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
h = {}
v = 0

('A'..'Z').each do |c|
  v+=1
  h[c] = v
end
```

h will result the hash you are looking for:

```
{"Z"=>26, "Y"=>25, "X"=>24, "W"=>23, "V"=>22, "U"=>21, "T"=>20, "S"=>19, "R"=>18, "Q"=>17, "P"=>16, "O"=>15, "N"=>14, "M"=>13, "L"=>12, "K"=>11, "J"=>10, "I"=>9, "H"=>8, "G"=>7, "F"=>6, "E"=>5, "D"=>4, "C"=>3, "B"=>2, "A"=>1}
```

To get a char's respective number, do:

```
h[char]
```

Eg. for `J` you can do: `h["J"]` to get `10`.

**Getting the char from integer:**

You can get the char from integer using hash#index.
Eg.

```
h.index(22) # => "V"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added a random number to that integer, but how do I transform the sum of those two values back into a character? Thanks

Comment: @DaniyartheKhan you can use #index for that purpose. See my edit

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy and quick way, using `String#bytes` and `Array#pack`.

```
# Get a list of the byte values of each character in a String
b = "Answering".bytes
# => [65, 110, 115, 119, 101, 114, 105, 110, 103]

# Add a random number between 0 and 100 to each integer
r = b.map {|x| x + x.rand(100)}
# => [78, 170, 172, 194, 175, 187, 135, 140, 180]

# Convert it back to a String
scrambled = r.pack('c*')
# => "N\xAA\xAC\xC2\xAF\xBB\x87\x8C\xB4"
```

Note that `Array#pack` may run into some trouble (hence the `\x...` characters) because there aren't enough bits in the normal encoding method to handle the higher byte integers that are created by adding the random number.

There's a more "Ruby" way to do this, which involves `Array#each_byte`, `#map`, and a block, but I'll leave that to you to figure out. This one (above) is probably more approachable for those who are used to procedural languages.

Comment: I got better results dropping the "x." and using: r = b.map {|x| x + rand(100)}